# Is there a synonym for the phrase "card up his sleeve"?

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, synonyms

"A card up his sleeve" means to have a secret advantage that you can use later; for example, *She still has one card up her sleeve*. This means that she has a secret plan, idea, or advantage that can be utilized if and when it is required. Now I am asking if there is any synonym that can replace this phrase?

Comment: If you add some context, you might get answers that are more closely tailored to your needs. In particular, why doesn't "card up his sleeve" work for you? Do you want a more formal term, or something without gambling associations? Something less colorful or more colorful? Is there a particular context where you want to use the phrase? And so forth.

Comment: Tangential: Dutch has a proverb for this, "they have a stick behind the door". To explain the image: consider someone opening the door to a stranger, but holding a baseball bat in the hand that is behind the door in case the stranger has ill intentions. The stranger should think twice before attacking the person, _because they may have a stick behind the door_. It is used much like "card up his sleeve", for any hidden benefit a person may have, not just aggressive/violent/defensive purposes as the example would suggest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a very similar phrase: "She still has a *trick* up her sleeve."

> #### trick up (one's) sleeve
>
> A secret plan, idea, or advantage that can be utilized if and when it is required. A reference to cheating at a card game by hiding a favorable card up one's sleeve. *I've got a few tricks up my sleeve if he decides to pursue legal action against me.*

(source: [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/trick+up+his+sleeve))

Comment: Flashbacks to the best episode of _Only Fools & Horses_ ever written!

Answer (score 10):

You're probably looking for

> **ace in the hole**
>   A secret advantage, or some kind of resource kept until needed. It refers to a high-value card in stud poker which is kept face down while bets are made.

[TFD Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ace+in+the+hole)

The "hole card" in stud is the card that is dealt first and remains face down until a showdown occurs.

Answer (score 8):

One (also informal) synonym is **secret weapon**:

> someone or something that gives you a special advantage over your opponents, especially in business or politics
>   *The show could be ABC’s secret weapon in the ratings war this fall.*
>   <sub>[Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/secret-weapon)</sub>

Answer (score 5):

[*trump card:*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trump-card)

an advantage that makes you more likely to succeed than other people, especially something that other people do not know about.

Answer (score 2):

I read your question as if you are looking for a word instead of a phrase. Maybe the word is "resourceful". I understand that to describe someone who always comes out of situations as if he had had a card up his sleeve.